# Collecting values from events

Tags: c#, events, functional-programming, handler, immutability

I have an event.
The event is fired from time to time and it calls an Event Handler that is an `Action<int>`.

Now I want to "collect" these integers the event is delivering me and save them in lists. I also want to specify the moment when a list is completed and a new list is started.

The naive solution I was thinking of is a property `List<int> ValList`. 
The Event Handler is adding a value everytime it is called.
The consumer side is taking the list when it wants to and will say from time to time `ValList = new List<int>();`
To avoid problems with thread synchronization I will need a lock, too.

I find this solution so terribly ugly and was wondering of alternatives.
With time I became more and more a functional programmer and I am using it very often.
But when it comes to problems like this I am still thinking to procedural.
I'd really like to avoid a mutable list (I am still using System.Collections.Immutable).

Is there a nice functional solution without mutables and side effects?

Comment: Try ConcurrentBag? https://www.dotnetperls.com/concurrentbag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using Reactive Extensions for this.  It deals with streams of values (events), and can remove the need for locks.

First I'm going to define some action classes for `Add`, `Complete`,and `RequestView` actions.  This is to behave like a discriminated union in F# for example:

```
public class EventAction
{
    public static EventAction Add(int value) => new AddAction(value);
    public static readonly RequestViewAction RequestView = new RequestViewAction();
    public static readonly EventAction Complete = new CompleteAction();
}

public class AddAction : EventAction
{
    public readonly int Value;
    public AddAction(int value) => Value = value;
}

public class CompleteAction : EventAction
{
}

public class RequestViewAction : EventAction
{
}
```

Next I'm going create a type called `AggregateView` it will hold three Rx `Subject` values:

- `aggregator` which will collect the `EventAction` events and manage an aggregated `Lst<int>`  (`Lst<int>` is an immutable list type from [the language-ext functional language extensions library](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/), but you can use `ImmutableList` too).
- `events` which will simply be a stream of the integer events
- `views` which will be a stream of `Lst<int>` views

Here's the class:

```
using System;
using LanguageExt;
using static LanguageExt.Prelude;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

public class AggregateView : IDisposable
{
    readonly Subject<EventAction> aggregator = new Subject<EventAction>();
    readonly Subject<int> events = new Subject<int>();
    readonly Subject<Lst<int>> view = new Subject<Lst<int>>();

    readonly IDisposable subscription;

    public AggregateView()
    {
        // Creates an aggregate view of the integers that responds to various control
        // actions coming through.  
        subscription = aggregator.Aggregate(
            Lst<int>.Empty,
            (list, action) =>
            {
                switch(action)
                {
                    // Adds an item to the aggregate list and passes it on to the 
                    // events Subject
                    case AddAction add:
                        events.OnNext(add.Value);
                        return list.Add(add.Value);

                    // Clears the list and passes a list onto the views Subject
                    case CompleteAction complete:
                        view.OnNext(Lst<int>.Empty);
                        return Lst<int>.Empty;

                    // Gets the current aggregate list and passes it onto the 
                    // views Subject
                    case RequestViewAction req:
                        view.OnNext(list);
                        return list;

                    default:
                        return list;
                }
            })
            .Subscribe(x => { });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Observable stream of integer events
    /// </summary>
    public IObservable<int> Events => 
        events;

    /// <summary>
    /// Observable stream of list views
    /// </summary>
    public IObservable<Lst<int>> Views =>
        view;

    /// <summary>
    /// Listener for plugging into an event
    /// </summary>
    public void Listener(int value) =>
        aggregator.OnNext(EventAction.Add(value));

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the aggregate view and post it to Views
    /// </summary>
    public void Complete() =>
        aggregator.OnNext(EventAction.Complete);

    /// <summary>
    /// Requests a the current aggregate view to be pushed through to 
    /// the Views subscribers
    /// </summary>
    public void RequestView() =>
        aggregator.OnNext(EventAction.RequestView);

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        subscription?.Dispose();
        view?.OnCompleted();
        events?.OnCompleted();
        view?.Dispose();
        events?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It has two `IObservable` properties:

- `Views` - which allows you to subscribe to the aggregate lists
- `Events` - which allows you to subscribe to the integer events

Also there are some useful methods:

- `Listener` - this is what you'll plug into your `event`
- `Complete` - this will empty the aggregate list and send an empty list through to the `View` observable
- `RequestView` - this will send the current aggregate list to all of the subscribers of the `Views` observable.

Finally to test it:

```
class Program
{
    static event Action<int> eventTest;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var aggregate = new AggregateView();
        eventTest += aggregate.Listener;

        aggregate.Views.Subscribe(ReceiveList);
        aggregate.Events.Subscribe(ReceiveValue);

        eventTest(1);
        eventTest(2);
        eventTest(3);
        eventTest(4);
        eventTest(5);

        aggregate.RequestView();
        aggregate.Complete();

        eventTest(6);
        eventTest(7);
        eventTest(8);
        eventTest(9);
        eventTest(10);

        aggregate.RequestView();
    }

    static void ReceiveList(Lst<int> list) =>
        Console.WriteLine($"Got list of {list.Count} items: {ListShow(list)}");

    static void ReceiveValue(int x) =>
        Console.WriteLine(x);

    static string ListShow(Lst<int> list) => 
        String.Join(", ", list);
}
```

This is the most functional way I can think of when dealing with events.  `Action<int>` should always be a *red flag* for anyone wanting to work functionally, because by default it has side-effects and isn't pure.  So you need to encapsulate the side-effects as much as possible and make everything else pure.

By the way, you can generalise this whole thing to work with any type.  Which makes it much more useful:

```
public enum EventActionTag
{
    Add,
    Complete,
    RequestView
}

public class EventAction<T>
{
    public readonly EventActionTag Tag;

    public static EventAction<T> Add(T value) => new AddAction<T>(value);
    public static readonly EventAction<T> RequestView = new RequestViewAction<T>();
    public static readonly EventAction<T> Complete = new CompleteAction<T>();

    public EventAction(EventActionTag tag) =>
        Tag = tag;
}

public class AddAction<T> : EventAction<T>
{
    public readonly T Value;
    public AddAction(T value) : base(EventActionTag.Add) =>
        Value = value;
}
public class CompleteAction<T> : EventAction<T>
{
    public CompleteAction() : base(EventActionTag.Complete)
    { }
}
public class RequestViewAction<T> : EventAction<T>
{
    public RequestViewAction() : base(EventActionTag.RequestView)
    { }
}

public class AggregateView<T> : IDisposable
{
    readonly Subject<EventAction<T>> aggregator = new Subject<EventAction<T>>();
    readonly Subject<T> events = new Subject<T>();
    readonly Subject<Lst<T>> view = new Subject<Lst<T>>();

    readonly IDisposable subscription;

    public AggregateView()
    {
        // Creates an aggregate view of the integers that responds to various control
        // actions coming through.  
        subscription = aggregator.Aggregate(
            Lst<T>.Empty,
            (list, action) =>
            {
                switch(action.Tag)
                {
                    // Adds an item to the aggregate list and passes it on to the 
                    // events Subject
                    case EventActionTag.Add:
                        var add = (AddAction<T>)action;
                        events.OnNext(add.Value);
                        return list.Add(add.Value);

                    // Clears the list and passes a list onto the views Subject
                    case EventActionTag.Complete:
                        view.OnNext(Lst<T>.Empty);
                        return Lst<T>.Empty;

                    // Gets the current aggregate list and passes it onto the 
                    // views Subject
                    case EventActionTag.RequestView:
                        view.OnNext(list);
                        return list;

                    default:
                        return list;
                }
            })
            .Subscribe(x => { });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Observable stream of integer events
    /// </summary>
    public IObservable<T> Events => 
        events;

    /// <summary>
    /// Observable stream of list views
    /// </summary>
    public IObservable<Lst<T>> Views =>
        view;

    /// <summary>
    /// Listener for plugging into an event
    /// </summary>
    public void Listener(T value) =>
        aggregator.OnNext(EventAction<T>.Add(value));

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the aggregate view and post it to Views
    /// </summary>
    public void Complete() =>
        aggregator.OnNext(EventAction<T>.Complete);

    /// <summary>
    /// Requests a the current aggregate view to be pushed through to 
    /// the Views subscribers
    /// </summary>
    public void RequestView() =>
        aggregator.OnNext(EventAction<T>.RequestView);

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        subscription?.Dispose();
        view?.OnCompleted();
        events?.OnCompleted();
        view?.Dispose();
        events?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: After 1.5 hours of googling I found this! Thank you so much!

Comment: So basically use the the AggregateView to convert and organize events from arbitrary event store into IObservable, then use the AFF extension Consume to work with the IObservable.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm fully understanding what you're saying your event is locked to Action and you have no control over that events signature. You're wanting to collect each int passed until some point at which an external request comes to retrieve the list with any accumulated integers, at which point the list resets and time information about the collection is saved. Is that correct?

What confuses me is why you mention functional programming in a language that is meant to be OOP? You might argue LINQ is functional to some degree, but surely there are better options for the functionally-minded? Because this seems like a pretty easy solution with an accumulator manager class.

```
namespace bs
{
struct CollectionEvent
{
    public DateTime Retrieved { get; set; }      
    public String IP { get; set; }  
}

static class Accumulator
{
    private static List<int> Items { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    private static bool Mutex { get; set; } = false;
    private static List<CollectionEvent> Collections { get; set; } = new List<CollectionEvent>();

    public static void Add(int i)
    {
        Sync(() => Items.Add(i));
    }

    public static List<int> Retrieve(String IP)
    {
        Collections.Add(new CollectionEvent
        {
            Retrieved = DateTime.UtcNow,
            IP = IP
        });

        List<int> dataOut = null;
        Sync(() =>
        {
            dataOut = new List<int>(Items);
            Items = new List<int>();
        });

        return dataOut;
    }

    public static void Sync(Action fn)
    {
        const int Threshold = 10;
        int attempts = 0;

        for (; Mutex && (attempts < Threshold); attempts++)
            Thread.Sleep(100 * attempts);

        if (attempts == Threshold)
            throw new Exception(); // or something better I'm sure

        Mutex = true;
        fn();
        Mutex = false;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var r = new Random();
        var m = r.Next(5, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            var datum = r.Next(100, 10000);
            Console.WriteLine($"COLLECT {datum}");
            Accumulator.Add(datum);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("RETRIEVE");
        Accumulator.Retrieve("0.0.0.0").ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine($"\t{i}"));

        m = r.Next(5, 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            var datum = r.Next(100, 10000); 
            Console.WriteLine($"COLLECT {datum}");
            Accumulator.Add(datum);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("RETRIEVE");
        Accumulator.Retrieve("0.0.0.0").ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine($"\t{i}"));

        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: C# is a functional language whether you think it is or not.  Just because it started life in the OO world doesn't mean that where it is now is purely OO.  It has first class functions, lambdas, monadic expressions (LINQ); in fact everything needed for functional programming.  The OP has clearly seen the light with functional programming, but wants to use it in his favourite language.  So telling him that he's doing it wrong and he should use another language, and then providing an answer which isn't what he asked for is why I voted you down. Voting my accepted answer down is childish.